# How to restrict the openlayers fullscreen in browser only

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5, html5-fullscreen

The default openlayers fullscreen api covers the entire window when clicked on the fullscreen control in openlayers map. Is there a way to control this behaviour and allow the fullscreen to expand only in the browser body so that user can still see the tabs open and address bar.

Comment: You would need change the map div using js and css.  Take a look at these examples  http://jsfiddle.net/a7nzy6w6/1/   https://codepen.io/colinlohner/pen/pwGozJ  oerhaps using a custom control e.g. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html

Comment: setting height and width of div containing map to 100% worked.